# Creating a future-proof URL to a self-hosted podcast feed

Tags: php, xml, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rss

I want to use "https://feed.example.com" as an URL for a podcast feed I'm self-hosting ("example.xml"), and want it to be displayed in the browser as if I was opening the file locally (document tree).

- I have a working feed named "example.xml"
- The URL I'm currently using is "https://example.com/feed/example.xml"
- Browsers show my URL as "feed:https://example.com/feed/example.xml"
- Instead of displaying the document tree: "no RSS is installed"

In short

- I want the displayed URL to be "https://feed.example.com"
- the "raw" XML to be shown in the browser (document tree)

I'm looking at a bunch of ".htaccess" tutorials, tipps and tricks, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Thank you!